# Interaction of Time Fixed Effect with one Past Outcome

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, dynamic-regression

I am trying to understand the identification of the following model:

$y_{it} = \gamma_i + \eta_t+\epsilon_{it}$ $\forall t\leq \bar{t}$

$y_{it} = \gamma_i + \eta_t\times y_{i\bar{t}}+\epsilon_{it}$ $\forall t>\bar{t}$

Also assume weak exogeneity, i.e.:

$\epsilon_{it} \perp y_{it'}, \forall{t'<t}$.

What I want to estimate are $\eta_t, \forall{t}$ of course subject to a suitable normalization.

It seems that usual fixed effects estimation will lead to the Nickel bias. I.e.:

$y_{it}-y_{i\bar{t}}=\eta_t\times y_{i\bar{t}} - \eta_{\bar{t}} + \epsilon_{it} - \epsilon_{i\bar{t}}$

Clearly assumption:

$\epsilon_{it} - \epsilon_{i\bar{t}} \perp y_{i\bar{t}}$

Does not hold. What I could do, I could use Arrelano Bond type tricks to identify this model. Maybe somebody can suggest something else. Also would the problem be alleviated if I discretize $y_{it'}$.